# Working with boards in Phabricator

Tags: project-planning, phabricator, kanban

I think this question belongs here (but it is may get voted down).  My company is migrating from GitHub to Phabricator.  But, not sure how to implement the "boards" feature.  I've never worked on a team that used kanban.  We have created 8 different "projects" in Phabricator, but we are too small to have separate teams for each project. There are 4 columns for each board:

- backlog
- selected
- in progress
- done

How do people get 1 board for doing planning across projects.  The only thing I can think of is to create a "master" project that every task gets added to in addition to it's "real" project.  For example, an task might be:

- Allow support user to resent password reset email

And it would get tagged with the projects "master" and "support_app".

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: For our cross team projects, we create one for the team and assign tasks to the team and project -- basically what you just suggested in your second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You can plan an release and add milestones for product level and add multiple projects in it and spread it across team members in multiple projects in further small tasks.

Then you will have an individual task board for each team on team level tasks.
A team member then exist across multiple projects and you can also view , how an person is loaded across multiple projects.

If you want to look at bigger picture then you can see the milestones/release level status.